# Adding custom HTML tags to Ghost or Ghost Themes

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, ghost-blog, ghost

Hello wonderful people.

## Challenge

I am trying to create a **custom Ghost theme** which supports Google's Accelerated Mobile Pages, i.e. Google AMP but I am facing a problem with a specific custom tag used for images.

[Google AMP custom img tag](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/get_started/create/include_image.html)

```
<amp-img src="welcome.jpg" alt="Welcome" height="400" width="800"></amp-img>
```

Note the *amp-img* HTML tag.

## Probable Solution

I believe in order to create a custom HTML tag for Ghost, I would need to modify core "server" Ghost files?

## Current Progess

Progress so far is here on [my GitHub project, Ampsper v0.0](https://github.com/varun-d/ampsper)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

Finally, [Ghost release 0.10.0](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/releases/tag/0.10.0) has AMP (Google Accelerated Mobile Pages) support built right into the system.

Extract from [Ghost's AMP Documentation](https://themes.ghost.org/docs/amp):

> The `{{image}}` helper needs to be wrapped in an `<amp-img>` tag and must provide a width and height property and works only for post images. `{{author.image}}` is not supported, in amp context, but the `{{image}}` helper can still be used within the `{{#author}}{{/author}}` block expression.

examples below:

#### For post images:

```
{{#post}}
    <amp-img src={{image absolute="true"}} width="600" height="400" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
{{/post}}
```

#### For author images:

```
{{#post}}
  {{#author}}
    <amp-img src={{image absolute="true"}} width="50" height="50"></amp-img>
  {{/author"}}
{{/post}}
```

Answer (score 0):

the new version of ghost has support for this, but i don´t belive that exist support for this tag i check my code and find this

```
<figure class="post-image">
<amp-img src="http://www.hackemate.ninja/content/images/2016/08/pablo--4--min.png" width="600" height="400" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
</figure>
```

however my normal theme has alt atribute in this section

Comment: Yup, you are right. The latest release has Amp support by default. I found out after speaking to the devs on their Slack channel.